# QString split also splitting at '.'

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregularexpression

I have a textField in my calculator app and I am splitting the whole input in the end to separate numbers and operators. For getting numbers I am using this:

```
QStringList nums = displayVal.split(QRegularExpression("[\+\-\/\*]"));
```

The problem is that it is also splitting at "." for some reason. I am not that familiar with Regular expressions so it the fault is probably in my regular expression. So what should I do to split at "+", "-", "*" and "/" only?

Example text:
4+2/3.5

Should get [4, 2, 3.5]. Of course the values will be in QString.

Comment: Use `QRegularExpression("[-+/*]")`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: Yes, the hyphen must be at the start/end of the character class, and if you plan to escape it, do it with double backslashes in the regular string literal (one is enough in raw string literals)